# Excel Lookup return multiple values horizontally while removing duplicates

Tags: excel, return-value, multiple-instances, vlookup, vba

I would like to do a vertical lookup for a list of lookup values and then have multiple values returned into columns for each lookup value. I actually managed to do this after a long Google search, this is the code:

```
=INDEX(Data!$H$3:$H$70000, SMALL(IF($B3=Data!$J$3:$J$70000, ROW(Data!$J$3:$J$70000)-MIN(ROW(Data!$J$3:$J$70000))+1, ""), COLUMN(A$2)))
```

Now, my problem is, as you can see in the formula, my lookup range contains 70,000 rows, which means a lot of return values. But most of these return values are double. This means I have to drag above formula over many columns until all lookup values (roughly 200) return #NUM!.

Is there any possible way, I guess VBA is necessary, to return the values after duplicates have been removed? I'm new at VBA and I am not sure how to go about this. Also it takes forever to calculate having so many cells.

Comment: Hi Ampi - just to clarify, you have a list of 200 values and a lookup table of 70000 values to compare them against. For each of those 200 values, you want to display all matches from the lookup table, each in their own column. This would result in the 200 values in Column A, with Column B, C, D ... populated with the matches. Is that accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edited]

You can do what you want with a revised formula, not sure how efficient it will be with 70,000 rows, though.

Use this formula for the first match

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$H3:$H70000,MATCH($B3,Data!$J3:$J70000,0)),"")`

Now assuming that formula in in **F5** use this formula in G5 confirmed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` and copied across

=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!$H3:$H70000,MATCH(1,($B3=Data!$J3:$J70000)*ISNA(MATCH(Data!$H3:$H70000,**$F5:F5**,0)),0)),"")

changed the bolded part depending on location of formula 1

This will give you a list without repeats.....and when you run out of values you get blanks rather than an error

Comment: Okay, looks good, I'm gonna give it a try. Only thing is, that it takes already a lot of time to calculate the current formulas. Maybe VBA could be quicker or is that an illusion?

Comment: Nevermind, it works really well, and better than any of the other solutions I've found using countif. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're still after a VBA answer but this should do the job - takes about 25 seconds to run on my machine - it could probably be accelerated by the guys on this forum:

```
Sub ReturnValues()

Dim rnSearch As Range, rnLookup As Range, rnTemp As Range Dim varArray
As Variant Dim lnIndex As Long Dim strTemp As String

Set rnSearch = Sheet1.Range("A1:A200") 'Set this to your 200 row value range
Set rnLookup = Sheet2.Range("A1:B70000") 'Set this to your lookup range (assume 2
columns)

varArray = rnLookup

For Each rnTemp In rnSearch
    For lnIndex = LBound(varArray, 1) To UBound(varArray, 1)
        strTemp = rnTemp.Value
        If varArray(lnIndex, 1) = strTemp Then
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rnTemp.EntireRow, varArray(lnIndex, 2)) = 0 Then 'Check if value exists already
                Sheet1.Cells(rnTemp.Row, rnTemp.EntireRow.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value =
varArray(lnIndex, 2)
            End If
        End If
    Next Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm definitely giving this a try!